# Imap headerinfo multiple from addresses?

Tags: php, imap

In what scenario is it possible for the `imap_headerinfo` method to return an array with multiple `from` objects?

As far as i know theres only one sender right?

Example:

```
[from] => Array(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [mailbox] => exampel
            [host] => test.com
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [mailbox] => exampel2
            [host] => test.com
        )
)
```

Comment: It's unconventional, but it is allowed to have more than one From;  RFC2822: `The from field consists of the field name "From" and a
   comma-separated list of one or more mailbox specifications.`